# How to increase accuracy in Convolutional neural network

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am implementing flower recognition - the dataset has few types of flowers.
Totally the dataset contains about 4000 images

My code -

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', input_shape=(32, 32, 3), activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(5, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
history=model.fit(x_train,y_train,batch_size=64,epochs=7,validation_data=(x_test, y_test),shuffle=True)
```

From this, I get the accuracy and loss

[Accuracy scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiaWj.png)

[Loss scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z56zw.png)

Then, I need more accuracy. So, I just increase the epochs=30 and the results are

(FOR epochs = 30)

[Accuracy scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVtpc.png)

[Loss scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVhfl.png)

I understand that neural network set random weights so that we get different results. But how can I improve the accuracy. I am new to neural nets. Would greatly appreciate some explanation. Thank you

Comment: Deep learning is much of an empirical field. There are no strict rules, just guidelines. I suggest you follow some courses on CNN, udacity has a nice free course on deep learing in pytorch (https://www.udacity.com/course/deep-learning-pytorch--ud188). In general though, the first thing you should try is to improve the training set with e.g. data augmentation.

Comment: To increase the amount of 'different' training examples, you could add the mirror images of your original train set to the train set (don't add the mirror images of your test set to the train set!). For more such data augmentation have a look at https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator-class

Comment: Try reducing dropout in first conv block, try different optimzers, loss functions etc.

Answer (score 1):

According to the training and validation metrics, the model seem to have over fitted. That is why training accuracy is increasing while validation accuracy seems constant. The reason for over-fitting is the lack of training samples.
You may have to increase the number of training samples. Try followings one by one.

- Reduce the dropout rate to ~0.2.
- Try reducing number of convolution layers

Please update a link to data-set if you want us to try a model with that.

Comment: Data augmentation or simply getting more data seem like the only hope.

Reducing the number of conv layers is a good idea, but I don't think think you can train a decent classifier then with such a small network. Changing dropout is unlikely to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have enough data samples. I recommend you to try the following:

1. Remove the activation from convolutional layers.
2. After each convolutional layer, apply BatchNormazalization
3. After each batch normalization, now apply activation e.g Relu

You can also try to increase number of kernels in convolutional layers and reducing the batch size, maybe 32 or 16